# Should I be using Malloc? Errors with large array of objects

Tags: c++

I'm using a bit of legacy type code that runs on a framework, so I can't really explain whats going on at a lower level as I don't know.

However my code creates an array of objectives.

```
int maxSize = 20;
    myObjects = new Object*[maxSize+1];

    myObjects[0] = new item1(this);
    myObjects[1] = new item2(this);

    for(int i=2; i != maxSize+1; i++){
          myObjects[i] = new item3(this);
        }

    myObjects[maxSize+1] = NULL;
```

If `maxSize` is larger than 30 I get a whole load of errors I've never seen. Visual Studio draws up an error in xutility highlighting:

```
const _Container_base12 *_Getcont() const
    {   // get owning container
    return (_Myproxy == 0 ? 0 : _Myproxy->_Mycont);
    }
```

I've never used Malloc before, but is this where the problem lies. Should I be assigning using it to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute value of `maxSize` is probably *not* a culprit: allocating 30 pointers should go without trouble on any computer, including most micro-controllers. Using `malloc` is not going to change anything: you are doing your allocation the way you're supposed to do it in C++.

Here is the likely source of your error:

```
myObjects[maxSize+1] = NULL;
```

You have allocated storage for `maxSize+1` items, so the valid indexes are between `0` and `maxSize`. Writing one past the last element is *undefined behavior*, meaning that a crash could happen. You got lucky with 20 elements, but 30 smoked out this bug for you. Using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) utility is a good way to catch memory errors that *could* cause crashes, even if they currently don't cause them.

```
int maxSize = 20;
myObjects = new Object*[maxSize+1];

myObjects[0] = new item1(this);
myObjects[1] = new item2(this);

// if maxsize is 1, this loop could be trouble
for(int i=2; i != maxSize; i++){
    myObjects[i] = new item3(this);
}

myObjects[maxSize] = NULL;
```

Comment: But the new Object*[maxSize+1] uses the same call, so the size is 20+1 21?

Comment: @EricBanderhide: Yes, but the 21 elements are indexed from 0 to 20. 21 is out of range.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit dim, what should I do instead then?

Comment: @EricBanderhide Assuming that you need precisely `maxSize` items, you need to end the loop at `i != maxSize`, and write `NULL` to `myObjects[maxSize] = NULL`.

Comment: Thanks dasblink, I still get the exact same error on larger sizes.

Comment: @EricBanderhide Then the error is somewhere else, perhaps in the constructor of `item1`, `item2`, or `item3`: the rest of the code from your post looks fine. You may want to put it through valgrind, it's usually good at finding errors.

Comment: Yes I think you must be right. It must be something in the underlying code.

Comment: Just to say thanks for the help, I found the other error, it was another data structure thats size was not large enough.

Answer (score 2):

You're going past the bounds with:

```
myObjects[maxSize+1] = NULL;
```

In your example, you created an array with 21 items. That will run from 0..20 but you're trying to write to the 21st element here.

The problem is not with `new` / `delete` as far as I can see, and I can't see any reason for switching to `malloc` here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `malloc()` in C++; you should use `new`.

There's one possible exception to this: if you have to allocate a block of memory which you intend to pass as an argument to a function which is going to eventually free it using `free()`. If you used `new` to allocate such a block the `free()` would likely cause heap corruption. But this is purely hypothetical -- I've never seen such an API!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access offset "maxSize+1". The solution is like:

```
myObjects = new Object*[maxSize+2];
...
myObjects[maxSize+1] = NULL;
```

Comment: While technically correct the proposed solution fills me with dread. Why go the `+2` route instead of changing the code to work to `maxSize` as is proper. A proper motivation may yet save you.